# Switching Between Bootstrap Tabs is Slow With Large Datasets

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I work for the public school system in Louisville, KY. I'm developing using html5, bootstrap, and asp.net/C#.

I'm developing a web page to display attendance data for our schools, approximately 180 schools total. The dataset is being pulled in from a SQL Server database and being dynamically built in the c# codebehind. The initial load of the data takes about 5 seconds to load all 180 schools.

The tabs are used to show filtered data -- the initial active tab shows All Students. The other tabs filter to show students who are on a lunch plan, at risk for dropping out, etc.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-success" style="margin-bottom: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                <div id="tabFilters" class="panel-heading" style="margin-bottom: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#all" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeFilter('All');">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#atRisk" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeFilter('atRisk');">At Risk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ECE" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeFilter('ECE');">ECE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ESL" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeFilter('ESL');">ESL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Gap" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeFilter('Gap');">Gap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#LEP" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeFilter('LEP');">LEP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#sec504" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeFilter('sec504');">Section 504</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body scrollHorizontal">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="all">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStudMthAll" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="atRisk">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStudMthAtRisk" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ECE">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStudMthECE" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ESL">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStudMthESL" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Gap">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStudMthGap" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="LEP">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStudMthLEP" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sec504">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStudMthSec504" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table class="no-result" style="width: 1000px; align-content: center">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bolder; color: red">No Results Found</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

During initial development I filtered the dataset down to show data for just one school. Everything worked great -- switching between tabs was extremely quick. However, when I removed the filter and started passing data in for every school, it started taking between 7-10 seconds to switch from one tab to another. My first thought was that it's a rather large dataset so maybe it's just taking a while to load. Using jQuery I placed a console message in the window.load event so I could tell when the page was finished loading. After it was fully loaded I tried switching to another tab -- and using the tab onclick event I sent another console message telling me that the new tab had been selected. This "here" message gets displayed immediately, but then there's still the 7-10 second lag before switching to it. And as you see below I've commented out the doPostBack and set a breakpoint in my page_load codebehind function to verify it isn't hitting the code behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Called when the tab changes
    function changeFilter(filterType) {
        $("#filterType").val(filterType);

        console.log("here");
        //__doPostBack();
    }

    $(window).load(function () {
        console.log("done");
    });
</script>
```

At this point, I've removed all data loading events from the initial non-active tabs so that when they are selected, it should just display an empty panel immediately. The only data that is getting loaded is the initial page load, which as I mentioned takes about 5 seconds.  Doing this and selecting a new tab after the load is completed is still taking 7-10 seconds. If I don't load any data at all, including not loading the initial data load, switching between the tabs becomes extremely quick again.

Any suggestions why the large dataset would be causing such a delay between switching tabs?

Comment: I was very interested in seeing an answer to this question.  Have you tried anything like Jmeter or any kind of load balancing software?  I'm not sure that would even be relative here, just trying to get some action on it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I admit I wasn't familiar with Jmeter and just googled it...it looks like it could possibly point me in a direction, but as a government employee I try hard to not spend money unless I absolutely have to.  I'm going to keep looking into it, but if I don't get any other ideas I may come back and revisit this...

Comment: I just found a work-around to the problem, but I'm curious to see if anybody else has run into this. The problem is definitely related to the size of the html table being viewed in the tab panel. One of the tabs filters roughly 85% of the student population out so it creates a relatively small table. When on this tab and switching to a different tab, it's noticeably quicker. As a solution, now I'm simply deleting the table using jQuery.remove() in the tab onClick event before calling __doPostBack().

Comment: I was also facing similar problem. In my case the data was loaded on the initial page load using ajax. I have 2 large jquery datatables and 2 small normal html tables on that particular tab, close to 500 rows. The page would become unresponsive for 2 seconds before showing the tab. As a solution, on the ```show.bs.tab``` event i set the tables as ```display:none``` , and then show them again on the `shown.bs.tab` event within a settimeout of 0.8 second.